# Using mouseover in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All,

```
var a='<div id="details"  onmouseover="tip(this)">';

function tip(el)
{
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
    var b="<div id='test'>"+el.innerHTML+"</div>";
    $(b).css("display", "inline");
    });
}
```

Is anything wrong with the above code? I am trying to display el.innerhtml on mouserover next to the hyperlink

Comment: This is likely very easy to answer if we knew what it was you want to happen so I think it would help if you explained what you wanted to do. c0mrade's answer is good, but it's hard for anyone to know if that's what you really need without it being clear what your end goal is. The above code doesn't  actually do anything so in this case it's difficult to judge what it is you'd like to happen when someone mouses over an element, if you can explain that above I'm sure you'll get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: My requirements are such that i have a multiple select boxand i have quite a few data in it so on mouse over this data this is invoked
var a='<div id="details"  onmouseover="tip(this)">';
My requirements are instead of adding title attribute i need to show the title attributes in a different menu

Comment: Suggest you add your comment into the body of your email. I notice also you have a tend not to vote. (62 questions, 1 vote). People may be a little more generous of you were more include to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to expand on what you want. Give us a list of requirements spell out exactly what you want. I expect a couple of the down votes will be rescided if you do this.

For my part, try this:

```
<div id="details">


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#details").mouseover(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append("<div id='test'>"+$this.html()+"</div>");
        });
    })
</script>
```

To show/hide would have been simple call to `.show()` or `.hide()`

If you really wanted this code:

```
var a='<div id="details"  onmouseover="tip(this)">';
```

Then you would have to append to the DOM:

```
$(document).append('<div id="details">');
```

And then bind your event:

```
$("#details").mouseover(function(){
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not try this instead :

```
 function tip(el) {
     $(this).mouseover(function() {
     $("#test").html(el.innerHTML);
     $("#test").css("display","inline");
     }); }
```

Comment: Then you need to clarify what exactly do you want .. you question seems wrong, hence the vote downs

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the code to your page DOM so it could be displayed. Currently you create a div, set CSS for it but it's still only in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$(this)` inside your function, maybe it should be `$(el)`? And you need to do something like `$('body').append(b);` as well to add the `<div>` to the DOM.

Comment: Is it that hard to type 'you' and 'are'? Also just looking in the jQuery documentation for append will show you plenty of examples. http://api.jquery.com/append/